# Issue with JFrame flashing upon repaint method

Tags: java, swing

So I have read in multiple places that you should not draw directly onto the JFrame. Could someone please be a bit more specific on how to do this. So if I have a class like this. My objective is to minimize flashing and take advantage of the double buffering.

```
    public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
    public GameFrame(){
    super("FOOBAR");
    this.setSize(480,480);
    this.repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String[] a){
    //what is a better way of doing this
    GameFrame g=new GameFrame();
    while(true){
    g.repaint();
    }
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    //I am not supposed to this
    g.clearRect(0,0,480,480);
    /**implementation not shown*/
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you read the [painting/graphics tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)? If not, why not read them first? Closed as yet another Swing painting question best answered by doing the obvious: please read the docs.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Could you please point me to a tutorial. Perdemoff. My question is how can i take advantage of the double buffering, and not have to override the paint method

Comment: Already done so. Also, if you hover over the [tag:swing], click on the info link for more. But your question shows that you haven't even investigated this sufficiently yet.

Comment: Sorry just saw that link. I have found other questions on it. But I have never found specifics on how to actually implement it.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial.